# If divergence is zero, is it necessarily a curl?

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis

The divergence of the curl of a vector is zero.
But,
Any vector whose divergence is zero can be the curl of a vector field ?

Comment: Have a look at this: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoidal_vector_field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with the caveat that your vector field is defined on a domain that doesn't have any voids.